# HTTP proxy not working on HTC desire running android 2.2

Tags: android, http, proxy

I am using an HTTP proxy using the following code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, "http");
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

This works fine on several android devices, all running android 2.3 and higher. However, when I try this on an HTC desire running android 2.2.2 I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:98)
java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:89)
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:238)
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.java:35)
org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
de.bahn.android.ris.communication.http.EasySSLSocketFactory.createSocket(EasySSLSocketFactory.java:136)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:225)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:302)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:146)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:623)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:352)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/15755/, this appears to be a bug that was resolved at some point, most likely after 2.2. I found the solution to this here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2690, which is to replace

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
```

with

```
int port = httpRequest.getURI().toString().startsWith("https") ? 443 : 80;
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(httpRequest.getURI().getHost(), port, httpRequest.getURI().getScheme());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(host, httpRequest);
```

Apparently the problem was that the port wasn't being set correctly and was set to 0 in InetSocketAddress.